# Gerar texto a partir de uma combobox

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou criando um programa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber como posso gerar um código selecionando um dos itens da combobox. Por exemplo: eu seleciono o item "Questão resolvida", na textbox iria aparecer "Questão marcada como resolvida".

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer verificar quando o selecionado na Combo box existir nas opções e criar uma mensagem pra isso.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged
        If ComboBox1.Items.Contains(Trim(ComboBox1.Text)) Then
            'Ação ocorre se o texto da Combo box conter nos itens da Combo box
            Dim m As String = ""
            Select Case ComboBox1.Text
                Case "Questão resolvida" 'texto da Combo box
                    m = "Questão marcada como resolvida" 'mensagem se a questão for resolvida
                Case "Questão anulada"
                    m = "Questão marcada como anulada" 'mensagem se a questão for anulada
            End Select
            TextBox1.Text = m
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

TextBox1.text é a saida do texto.

ComboBox1 é a Combo Box.

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado pela sua ajuda!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Combo1.AddItem "Text1"
  Combo1.AddItem "Text2"
  Combo1.AddItem "Text3"
  Combo1.AddItem "Text4"
End Sub


Private Sub Combo1_Click()
  'ListIndex inicia com 0 (zero)
  Dim strTeste As String
  Select Case Combo1.ListIndex
  Case 0
    strTeste = "Text1"
  Case 1
    strTeste = "Text2"
  Case 2
    strTeste = "Text3"
  Case 3
    strTeste = "Text4"
End Select
   If Combo1.Text = strTeste Then MsgBox "OK!"
End Sub
```